# Proving that $1+2^m+3^m+...n^m$ is divisible by $(n+1)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Proving that

> $$1+2^m+3^m+...n^m$$ is divisible  by $$(n+1)$$ 
>   where 
>   $n$=Integer even number
>
> $m=$positive integer number, so that $m\neq n,2n,3n...$

Comment: In fact,I found this relation by using my calculator, but I couldn't how to start to prove it.

Comment: **Hint:** $n\equiv-1\bmod n+1$, $n-1\equiv-2\bmod n+1$, etc.

Comment: Isn't that very closely related to the (unsolved) Agoh/Giuga-conjecture?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not true. For example, if $n=8$ and $m=2$ we have
$$\sum_{k=1}^8 k^2=204$$
which is not divisible by $9$.

The reason why numerical examples suggested this formula is because it is true in the case $n+1$ is prime, or when $m$ is odd. That's why I looked at $n=8$.

If $n+1$ is prime, the claim is true: you can prove that $f(x)=x^m$ is a permutation of the Units in $\mathbb Z /p \mathbb Z$, and the result follows from here.

If $m$ is odd, then the result is also true: group first and last, second first and second last  and so on. Then
$$k^{2l+1}+(n+1-k)^{2l+1}\\
=\left( k+n+1-k \right)\left( k^{2l}-k^{2l-1}(n+1-k)+..- k(n+1-k)^{2l-1} + k(n+1-k)^{2l}\right)\\
=\left( n+1 \right)\left( \mbox{junk}\right)$$

Alternately you can use that 
$$n^m \equiv (-1)^m=-1 \pmod{n+1} \\
(n-1)^m \equiv (-2)^m=-2^m  \pmod{n+1} \\
(n-2)^m \equiv (-3)^m=-3^m  \pmod{n+1} \\
....$$